# AT&T to Intel Syntax

Tags: assembly, intel, att

I want to translate following lines from AT&T to Intel (nasm) :

This is my AT&T-Code:

```
   .equ BUFFEREND, 1
   .lcomm buffer, BUFFEREND
    cmpb $97, buffer
```

And here is my Intel-Code:

```
   BUFFEREND EQU 1
   buffer db BUFFEREND
   cmp BYTE [buffer], 97
```

What is wrong with my Translation? I have the lines from the following code.
The AT&T-Code works. It translates all undercase characters in one file in uppercase characters and save it in a new file. :

```
.global _start

.equ BUFFEREND, 1
.lcomm buffer, BUFFEREND

_start:

movl %esp, %ebp

movl $5, %eax
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
movl $0, %ecx
int $0x80

pushl %eax

movl $5, %eax
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
movl $03101, %ecx
movl $0666, %edx
int $128

pushl %eax

loop:
movl -4(%ebp), %ebx
movl $3, %eax
movl $buffer, %ecx
movl $BUFFEREND, %edx
int $128

pushl %eax

cmpb $97, buffer
jl next_byte
cmpb $122, buffer
jg next_byte

subb $32, buffer

next_byte:

movl %eax, %edx
movl $4, %eax
movl -8(%ebp), %ebx
movl $buffer, %ecx
int $0x80

popl %eax

cmpl $BUFFEREND, %eax
jne loopexit

jmp loop

loopexit:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

The exact probleme is that my intel-file creates no outputfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.lcomm` creates a zero-initialized variable of the given size in the `.bss` section. As such, your `buffer db BUFFEREND` should be modified accordingly, as per the syntax of your assembler. Unfortunately you have forgotten to specify which one you use. For `nasm` the equivalent could be:

```
section .bss
buffer resb BUFFEREND
```

Also you have forgotten to mention what the exact problem is.

Comment: oh sorry, I am using `nasm` for intel and `as`for AT&T syntax

Comment: Check your parameters for the second open. I think they should be octal? `mov ecx, 3031q` for Nasm?